# How to Parse Json data to normal data in C#

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I am beginner in c#, I have output from the website like {"result":"Invalid"} with my c# program, It seems to be **Json** ,I want to display these data as normal string and display it in message box and use those parsed data for validation

**Program:**

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  var username = Username.Text;
  var password = passbox .Password;   
  var postMessage = new StringContent(string.Format("username={0}&password={1}", username, password), Encoding.UTF8 , "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");   
  var response = await (new HttpClient()).PostAsync("http://xxx.xx.net/xx.php", postMessage);   
  var responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();           
  MessageBox.Show( responseBody );
}
```

I want to know how to display the **responseBody** as normal string ?

Comment: Can you pls let us know your desired output.

Comment: What's your exact JSON data?

Comment: I want to compare it like                                 if(responseBody =="Invalid")                       {messagebox.show();}

Comment: This is the exact data {"result":"Invalid"}

Comment: How to read the posted value from here to php file in server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using JSON.Net using below code if it returns result as output then

```
    string json = responseBody;
    JObject parsed = JObject.Parse(json);
    string results = (string)parsed["result"];
```

Answer (score 3):

Ideal solution depends on how complex Json string you got. If it has only single property-value pair like posted in question :

```
{"result":"Invalid"}
```

I think simple string manipulation logic will bring you the value (`"Invalid"`) easily. Like this naive code :

```
var jsonString = "{\"result\":\"Invalid\"}";
//remove "{" and "}" from sting
var result = jsonString.Replace("{", "").Replace("}", "");
//separate property name from it's value
var pair = result.Split(':');
//property will contain property name : "result"
var property = pair[0];
//value will contain property value : "Invalid"
var value = pair[1];
```

Otherwise, if JSON response is more complex, it is not reliable to use string manipulation. I'd suggest to go with Newtonsoft.Json library as also suggested by @Mohammad.

Comment: i would have used Newton Soft, but this is better

Answer (score 0):

To convert `JSON` object to string you should serialize it.
I'm using [Newtonsoft.Json](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/6.0.1)
After install above package you can use it as the following :

```
string jsonInString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(responseBody);
MessageBox.Show(jsonInString);
```

And for convert json string to an object you can use the following :

```
ClassName obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ClassName>(jsonInString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure if this is the best approach... But I'm currently implementing something similar, and using a reader to... read the returned data.

```
System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
string outputStr = reader.ReadToEnd();
```